# How know the last ajax call into a loop is back?

Tags: ajax

if I make 100 ajax call's, how can I know when te server makes the last call?
For example:

```js
y = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
      peticion_http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  
peticion_http.open('POST', 'http://www.mypage.com', true);
peticion_http.send(null);
   

peticion_http.onreadystatechange = muestraContenido;

function muestraContenido() {
 if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) {
  if(peticion_http.status == 200) {
          y++;
          if(y==99) {
            alert("anything");
          }
        }
    }

}
```

I thought that when each ajax call back's, will sum 1 to the var y, so at the end, will get the alert, but at the end of the calls, y = 1.
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with peticion_http, but is it possible that the problem is your nesting? In your code, the for loop is never closed, so the function definition is in the loop. possibly a source of trouble?

```js
y = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
      peticion_http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  
peticion_http.open('POST', 'http://www.mypage.com', true);
peticion_http.onreadystatechange = muestraContenido;
peticion_http.send(null);

}

function muestraContenido() {
 if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) {
  if(peticion_http.status == 200) {
          y++;
          if(y==99) {
            alert("anything");
          }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, just bad copy and paste, so the code it's ok :(

Comment: In that case, possibly send the counter for how many times you've iterated the call through with the request, and return it in the response object. Then you've got a count of what call you're on in your success function.